# People Picker Could Not List Founded Users

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, people-picker

When I typing username in PEOPLE PICKER it show me not found message but when I hit the Share button SharePoint notification appear and show me the Name of username that I entered and successfully share Team-Site with them

Does somebody knows what's going on with PEOPLE PICKER CONTROL??

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the people picker to only return users from a specific location?

Use this command to check the properties for the people picker:
stsadm.exe -o getproperty -pn  -url

Reference:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/gg602075(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: no i checked it too.